On premise Amazon S3 curl object upload command failing with 400 Bad Request
Due to some restrictions on our linux server I cannot use AWS CLI command. Hence I am trying to upload files to S3 using curl command. The S3 storage is on-prem. I am executing command like following:
curl -k -X PUT -T "/tmp/payload.txt" 
-H "Host: xyz-bl.s3.amazonaws.com" 
-H "Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2024 12:45:35 +345" 
-H "Content-Type: text/plain" 
-H "Authorization: AWS xyz-bl-usr:PAuh+xxxxxxxx" 
https://on-prem.s3.com:343/payload.txt

Authorization is being calculated as follows:
s3_resource="/${bucket_name}/${file}"
string_to_sign="PUT\n\n${content_type}\n${date_value}\n${s3_resource}"
signature=`echo -en ${string_to_sign} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${aws_secret_access_key} -binary | base64`

But this fails with 400 Bad Request error. I tried this command on both Windows (gitbash) and Ubuntu.
What is wrong with this command? Please help!

What do you mean by "the S3 storage is on-prem"?

It is hosted on premise. Dont have much details about it except the fact that the URL is not standard <bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com

Do you know which S3-like storage emulation this is? Minio, ceph, outposts, other? It would be useful to know that.

If it's not an AWS bucket, then the Host you pass into the HTTP call should not include amazonaws.com
